# How to overload delete[] operator to show number of bytes being freed?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm trying to overload new/delete operators, but apparently overloading delete[] operator to show number of bytes being freed is not doing anything. Below you can see my code (it compiles without any error), new and delete work fine, but delete[] is not even called. From what I've read on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete operator delete[] supports number of bytes as second paramter since C++14 (I'm currently using visual studio 2019 with C++17).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes.\n";

    if (void* ptr = malloc(size))
        return ptr;

    throw bad_alloc();
}

void operator delete(void* memory, size_t size) noexcept {
    cout << "Freeing " << size << " bytes.\n";
    free(memory);
}

void operator delete[](void* memory, size_t size) noexcept {
    cout << "Freeing " << size << " bytes.\n";
    free(memory);
}

int main() {
    int* a = new int[20];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation(item 5-6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) it is `"...unspecified whether [the overload that accepts a size_t parameter] is called when deleting objects of incomplete type and arrays of non-class and trivially-destructible class types"`.  So try removing the `size_t size` parameter (although it does rather defeat your purpose, sorry :-)

Comment: A minor point: `operator new[]` has a couple of additional requirements that aren't handled in this code. That doesn't affect the question, and the code is okay for quick-and-dirty investigations. but a real-world implementation would be more complex than this.

Comment: ...Replacing `int` with a simply struct `T` defined as `struct T { T(){} virtual ~T(){} };` results in the desired overload being invoked (g++ 10.2.1, libstdc++.so.6).

Comment: This probably isn't the issue, but keep in mind that stream inserters **might** allocate memory, which, in turn, would use your replacement `operator new` or `operator new[]`. So the rule of thumb when writing debug code for `operator new` and `operator delete` is to use `printf` rather than inserting into the standard streams.

Comment: Both gcc and clang selects 2 instead of 6 for `int[20]` (it's unspecified as @G.M.) mentioned. If you make it `std::string[20]`, gcc will select your replacement - but clang sticks with 2.

Comment: Is it possible to force the compiler (msvc) to use (5-6) versions instead of (1-2) ?